# Technology for realtime messaging to mobile apps

Tags: google-app-engine, mobile, real-time

We are developing a mobile game with app-engine as our backend.

We now want to add realtime messaging from our server to our clients. (IOS & android)

Note: We are not talking about push notifications.

Has anyone out there implemented realtime mobile apps and has any recommendations for us.

The Channel API is said not to be for mobile apps.
Google Cloud pub/sub is also said not to be for mobile apps.

Google Cloud Messaging may be an option but I got the feeling it's not right either.

We have looked at solutions like pubnub.com (which looks great) but it may be a bit too pricy since we hope for a huge success :-)

So our wish list is:

1. Deliver messages from app engine to mobile devices in realtime.
2. As cheap as possible since we hope for +50K daily users
3. IOS & Android API's or even better a Unity API.

Thanks in advance!

/Gunnar Eketrapp

Comment: I think this will be downvoted for being too broad and asking for recommendations, but have you looked at [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/)? Not really 'messaging' but possibly meets your 'realtime' requirement.

Comment: also do show us in detail whats wrong with GCM as you said you felt it wasnt right. (hint: it is right)

Comment: I got the impression that GCM was more for push notifications but I will give it another look!